# Azure Application Gateway Backend Servers Client Certificate for Authentication

Tags: azure-application-gateway

I have a backend VM that accepts connection only if a specific client certificate is provided to it . I am trying to get to a state where I lock that Backend VM to accept Calls only from the Application Gateway using these Client Certificates .

I tried updating the Backend trusted root certificate with the Client Certificate configured on the backend VM but things dosent seem to work. I do see that there is a provision to configure to Client Certificate on the Application Gateway side for Inbound using SSL profiles , is there way to acheive the same to make the AppGW authenticate with its backend using these certificates ?

Answer (score 0):

I created an application gateway with certificate like below:

[image]

Try to add a listener and routing rule and associate the backend pool as Virtual machine like below:

[image]

In-app gateway under SSL setting try to add SSL policy like below:

[image]

And in the listener under certificate you can select Enable SSL policy  in SSL profile it will add your ssl like below:

[image]

> ***Note***: According to [MsDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-ssl-portal)
>
> - Certificate Authorities (CAs) that have issued certificates: Most trusted certificate stores contain intermediate and root certificates, which enable trusted connections with minimal to no additional device settings.
> - CA certificates from certificate authorities recognized by the organization: These certificates are often privately produced by your company and are not recognised by other organizations. For clients to build chain trust, intermediate and root certificates must be imported into trusted certificate stores.

Then In virtual machine try to install IIS to verify application gateway

```
Set-AzVMExtension `
         -ResourceGroupName myResourceGroupAG `
         -ExtensionName IIS `
         -VMName myVM `
         -Publisher Microsoft.Compute `
         -ExtensionType CustomScriptExtension `
         -TypeHandlerVersion 1.4 `
         -SettingString '{"commandToExecute":"powershell Add-WindowsFeature Web-Server; powershell Add-Content -Path \"C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\Default.htm\" -Value $($env:computername)"}' `
         -Location <location>
```

[image]

Now, when I test my application gateway it hit IP address successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if this is what I was requesting , issue here is that I have a apache backend accepting connections only if its signed with a client certificate and I communictae to the backend apache server from appliucation gateway . I need to the application gateway to use an client certificate when its communicating with the backend